# how to run ng commands.?

Tags: visual-studio

C:\Users\mycom\Desktop\NeonUI-main>ng serve
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^15.0.0,
but Angular version 11.0.5 was found instead.

Need to works the ng commands in visual studio code

Comment: Please don't tag visual-studio when you meant visual-studio-code. They are completely different!

Comment: There appears to be a conflict between the versions of Angular CLI being used and the version of Angular in use. Try installing the appropriate angular cli to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,you can try to open integrated terminal with Ctrl ~. After that write down the “ng serve” command. It should show the message of successfull application and launch it in browser

Comment: _"If i understood correctly"_ I don't think you did. There appears to be a conflict between the angular-cli and the version of Angular being used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).